# Docker push to private registry error [denied: requested access to the resource is denied]

Tags: docker

I login like this:

```
PS C:\workl> docker login some-registry.io -u username@corp.company.com -p somePasswrod 
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
```

When I run docker images I get this

```
CREATED = user/custom-images
tag 1 
imageID=34e982156f
```

I then try to push

```
docker push user/custom-image:1
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/custom-image]
50c2af6d2450: Preparing
862d28b9e0d9: Preparing 
...
...
878dab86cf0f: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Why? I am adding a tag and have seen others online similar to this but don't seem to be able to find a solution. I can pull just fine.

Comment: If you want to push to `some-registry.io` you need to tag it like `docker image tag image:tag some-registry.io/path/image:tag` and push it as `docker image push some-registry.io/path/image:tag`. Without tagging the push will attempt to push to the default location which in your case is docker.io.

Answer (score 1):

you need to follow this steps to push to a container :

1/ create a repository inside docker hub  https://hub.docker.com/repositories :

just click on create a new repository.

2/ tagging your local image:
docker tag  /

the repo_name is the one you created in step 1

3/ commit the image :

```
docker commit <existing-container> <hub-user>/<repo-name>
```

4/ and finnaly push it :

```
docker push <hub-user>/<repo-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @altvits said,

If you want to push to `some-registry.io` you need to tag it like
`docker image tag image:tag some-registry.io/path/image:tag` and push it as `docker image push some-registry.io/path/image:tag`.

Without tagging the push will attempt to push to the default location which in your case is docker.io

Answer (score 0):

You have to change user into username@corp.company.com :

```
CREATED = user/custom-images
docker push user/custom-image:1
```

to

```
CREATED = username@corp.company.com/custom-images
docker push username@corp.company.com/custom-image:1
```